# get Request Params magento

Tags: magento

I am new with Magento
"Can anyone have example code or tutorial, help me :
In the Dev_Banner module (i already created)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHCXW.png), create a controller for the page banner detail with the address banner/index/view/id/1
Where 1 is the banner_id of any banner, the request in the controller can load the banner model"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can Create the Controller as follows -

First Create route -

> routes.xml

The location of the routes.xml file in a module, either **etc/frontend** or **etc/adminhtml**

based on the area you are working and inside the routes

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="banner" frontName="banner">
            <module name="Dev_Banner"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

After Creating the routes.xml you need to add the Controller Directory and then Adminhtml Directory then Index Directory and then View.php

> Controller/Adminhtml/Index/View.php

Inside View Controller add the code -

```
    <?php
    
    namespace Dev\Banner\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
    
    class View extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
    {

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            $this->request = $request;
        }
    
        public function execute()
        {
            $id= $this->request->getParam('id');
            //Do Your Logic Here
            $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
            $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Sales Order Import'));
            return $resultPage;
        }
    }
```